How to create a Todoist task from a Telegram message and link each other by URL
Normally we work by creating topics on Telegram groups. Quite often we want to create a task after a discussion or decision in Todoist.
Then we link the latest Telegram message to the Todoist.
We do it manually by doing this:
TELEGRAM: Right click to a message on Telegram - Copy Message Link:

TODOIST: Create task - Open the task - Click the 3 dots - Copy link to task:

How could we create a task in Todoist from Telegram and link each other in both directions? For example, if we write on Telegram:

/bot-c-todoist Example task

That message would trigger an automation that creates a task with name "Example task" in Todoist and would include a link to the Telegram message "/bot-c-todoist Example task"
Also, a new message would be in Telegram that could be something like:

Task created in todoist with name: "Example task". URL to the task: https://app.todoist.com/app/task/example-task-74567641094

Is there any tool or way to do something like that or another solution?
